# How to integrate CQ5/AEM pages with Facebook App

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, aem

I would like to know how to show a CQ5 page in a Facebook App without writing a dedicated sling servlet?
Facebook adds a form post to retrieve markup and insert into the iFrame.
Apparently, CQ5 pages doesn't allow POST operations unless you write a dedicated sling servlet to handle.

The page for some reason sits within `/content/dam`

Here's what the Facebook App add in the canvas:

```
<form action="<url>" method="post" target="iframe_canvas_fb_https" id="canvas_iframe_post_522050a15f2c72f17540952" onsubmit="return window.Event &amp;&amp; Event.__inlineSubmit &amp;&amp; Event.__inlineSubmit(this,event)"><input type="hidden" autocomplete="off" name="signed_request" value="TKQ-UKDi8meFDQgQaq_5c3LWD2R06EiibRdrTk7XldE.eyJhbGdvcml0aG0iOiJITUFDLVNIQTI1NiIsImlzc3VlZF9hdCI6MTM3Nzg0OTUwNSwidXNlciI6eyJjb3VudHJ5IjoiaGsiLCJsb2NhbGUiOiJlbl9HQiIsImFnZSI6eyJtaW4iOjIxfX19"><input type="hidden" autocomplete="off" name="locale" value="en_GB"></form>

<iframe class="smart_sizing_iframe" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" id="iframe_canvas" name="iframe_canvas_fb_https" src='javascript:""' height="800" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" oallowfullscreen="" msallowfullscreen="" style="height: 232px;"></iframe>
```

Comment: No framework will work with `POST` operations without having a dedicated handler… How would it decide what to do when it receives the post?

Comment: based on what i've researched thru the google group this is one of the quote "The underlying issue is that the Sling Post servlet is the default for any POST request. . . ". And since the page resides in a content dam, there is not dedicated sling servlet to handle such request.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is though? You're asking how to handle POST requests that don't follow default behaviour while still using the default servlet? This isn't possible. But what is the issue with writing a custom servlet?

Comment: Reason being the pages are residing in content dam. I was just thinking if i can overcome this default behavior by not writing a custom servlet.

Comment: Leaving that aside, the default behaviour of the POST servlet is to modify the JCR contents. Presumably, you don't want this initial request from Facebook to make modifications to this content & instead want to do a POST/Redirect/GET set-up? If that's the case, you'll need a custom handler no matter where the content resides. (You could do this via a JSP, but you'll need custom code either way & a servlet for a handler would be better practice.)

Comment: Understand what you meant. Thanks and appreciate for your advise.

Comment: Sure, no problem :) Good luck with it!